# New to react. IM having issues with nav bar. Js code is not responding

Tags: reactjs

any help would be much appreciated. again im new to coding and react. thank you in advance.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Nav extends Component { 

    openNav = () =>{
        document.getElementById("mySidenav");
      }
      
      closeNav = () => {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav");
      } 

    render() { 
 
        return(   
            <div id="main">
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick={this.closeNav()}>&times;</a>
                 <a href="#">About</a>
                 <a href="#">Services</a>
                 <a href="#">Clients</a>
                 <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
                 <h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
                 <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
                 <span onclick={this.openNav()}>open</span>
                 <script>
                     
                 </script>

            </div>
            
        );
    }
}
export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function but you are not doing anything substantial inside it. You want a state variable that can be used to toggle some a state variable. Changing the state variable will cause `rerender`, which is what you want.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Nav extends Component { 
     constructor(){
    this.state = {
           'show' : false;
     }
    }
    openNav = () =>{
         this.setState(prevState => !prevState);
      }
      
      closeNav = () => {
          this.setState(prevState => !prevState);      
     } 

    render() { 
 
        return(   
            <div id="main">
            {this.state.show && <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick={this.closeNav()}>&times;</a>
                 <a href="#">About</a>
                 <a href="#">Services</a>
                 <a href="#">Clients</a>
                 <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>}
                 <h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
                 <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
                 <span onclick={this.openNav()}>open</span>
                 <script>
                     
                 </script>

            </div>
            
        );
    }
}
export default Nav;
```

So you can just toggle the state and based on that show/hide the component.

Expressions like `a && b`, b is only evaluated if `a` is true. If `a` is false code does not reach `b`. And when b is evaluated it is returned, if it is a truthy value (which the nav code block is).

I have purposely kept two functions above. You might notice that you can do with one. Something like `toggleNav()`.

**Note:** Always better to use `refs` in react instead of document.querySelector.